# Getting value of Bootstrap TouchSpin

Tags: html

I am using the bootstrap touchspin script from http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/.

Everything works quite well to set the value - but I'm struggling to find out how to retrieve the newest value when I stop downspinning. If I am not wrong, the doc is not mentioning that either. Also, using Google and this site, I did not find out any answer on how to solve my issue.

```
    var i = $("input[name='demo7']"),
            demoarea = $("#demo7textarea"),
            text = "";

i.on("touchspin.on.stopspin", function () {
            writeLine("touchspin.on.stopspins" + "new value " + i.value );
        });
```

What am I missing? I hope my question is clear.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer from the developer.

Should be :

... $(this).val() instead of i.val()

Comment: You have `i.val()` in your original post. Did you "answer" it backwards or update the original post?